# Can any one please give sample code for sending values from CSV file via Bluetooth in android?

Tags: android, csv, bluetooth

Please give me sample code or reference link for sending values from a CSV file using android to another android device via bluetooth communication?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android developer page has tutorials and explains how to use the Bluetooth feature: [Bluetooth demo sample code provided by android develpoers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

I hope this helps.